# What's the meaning of 人 in 他们人退休了?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of 人 in *以前他们工作的时候忙得没有时间唱。现在他们人退休了。*?

Answer (score 3):

人 is an appositive of 他们. You can just delete it without changing the meaning!